# Postgres log destination per function/procedure

Tags: postgresql

1. Is it possible in Postgres to define on a function/procedure level a different log destination than is defined in conf file (in addition or instead).
2. Can the log destination be set on a C# Postgres connection level or when calling the function from C# code.

I know in psql it can be directed to output file, but I do not execute my code from psql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The best you can do is have the function emit `NOTICE` messages and collect them on the client.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean collecting them in c# code?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But it might be easier to debug the function with an interactive client like `psql`. There, the messages are simply displayed on the terminal.